# Mongodb how to get $type "object"

Tags: mongodb, types, mongodb-query

Can somebody tell me please how to get items which field is $type object? The problem is that **Mongodb includes $type array (which contains objects)** to result. But I dont want arrays but objects.

```
{fieldName: {$type: 3}}
```

returns items like:

```
{
    _id: xxxx,
    fieldName: [
        {a: 'aaa'}, 
        {b: 'bbb'}
    ]
}
```

Comment: Could you share any example ?

Comment: There it is.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Aggregation Framework's [$type](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/type/) operator:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            $expr: {
                $eq: [ { $type: "$fieldName" }, "object" ]
            }
        }
    }
])
```

> Unlike the $type query operator, which matches array elements based on their BSON type, the $type aggregation operator does not examine array elements. Instead, when passed an array as its argument, the $type aggregation operator returns the type of the argument, 
>   i.e. "array".

[MongoDB Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hPVdVIP1Z4K)

Comment: Did you try the playground ?

Comment: No I did not notice it.It works well. I tried it in Compass and it is bit stupid and don't support Mongodb syntax in some cases.